# Obtaining additional information with WMI

Tags: delphi, memory, wmi, motherboard, chipset

I have a question, if you can get the HD speed (RPM), if memory is DDR1, DDR2, DDR3, if the HD is SATA or IDE socket and chipset and motherboard ...
If it is possible to phase it in Delphi

Thank You

Answer (score 7):

To check if the memory is DDR1, DDR2, DDR3 you can use the [`Win32_PhysicalMemory`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa394347%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) wmi class and the `MemoryType` property.

To check if the HDD is SATA or IDE you can use the [Win32_DiskDrive](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa394132%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), [Win32_IDEController](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa394155%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and [Win32_SCSIController](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa394400%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) WMI classes.

for chipset info check the [`Win32_VideoController`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa394512%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) class

for Motherboard information use the [`Win32_BaseBoard`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa394072%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) class.

Now for access these WMI classes using Delphi code you can use the [WDCC (WMI Delphi Code Creator)](http://code.google.com/p/wmi-delphi-code-creator/) tool.

Comment: In Win32_PhysicalMemory - MemoryType returns 0 or unknown, and the
two cards I have are DD3 memory.
Already in Win32_DiskDrive returned IDE me more if my SATA is in Win32_IDEController me not returned
what I needed and I returned also Win32_SCSIController not what I need.
On Motherboard I do not have the information it's Socket.

If you can help me ...

thank you

Comment: If some of the above classes are not retrieving the info which you are looking for, you must post `a separate question` for each class, posting the current code which you are using and the version of windows.

Comment: It would be useful I just get caught up memory is DDR2, DDR3 and type of HD, SATA or IDE ...

The properties I have no more are correct.